# Would these two statements be logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is an excerpt from my textbook(Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th edition)
[image]

When I tried doing this example on my own, my answer was "There is a student x in this class and that student x has visited Mexico". Would that be logically equivalent or the same as the answer that the author came to? They both express the idea that there exists a student in that class that has visited Mexico. I am just not sure if the author went out of his way to use with the property and not just and?

Comment: You are correct. They are logically equivalent. He went out of his way to add emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, but this shouldn't be about playing with words. One needs to do this more formally:

Let $A(x)$ be the predicate "$x$ is a student in this class" and let $B(x)$ be the predicate "$x$ has visited Mexico". Now one can write the sentence as
$$\exists x, A(x)\land B(x).$$

Comment: How did you include the sign for exists? Or you could specify domain as students in the class and just do ∃xB(x) where B(x) is predicate x has visited Mexico?

Comment: @committedandroider I don't understand your first question, but yes, if $\forall x, A(x)$ is true, then you need only that $\exists x, B(x)$.

Comment: Like I cant type the opposite pointing E. I have to copy and paste it each time

Comment: @committedandroider Oh, just type "\$\exists\$".